# Optimal CPU utilization thresholds

Tags: performance, multithreading, cpu, throughput

I have built software that I deploy on Windows 2003 server.  The software runs as a service continuously and it's the only application on the Windows box of importance to me.  Part of the time, it's retrieving data from the Internet, and part of the time it's doing some computations on that data.  It's multi-threaded -- I use thread pools of roughly 4-20 threads.

I won't bore you with all those details, but suffice it to say that as I enable more threads in the pool, more concurrent work occurs, and CPU use rises. (as does demand for other resources, like bandwidth, although that's of no concern to me -- I have plenty)

My question is this: should I simply try to max out the CPU to get the best bang for my buck?  Intuitively, I don't think it makes sense to run at 100% CPU; even 95% CPU seems high, almost like I'm not giving the OS much space to do what it needs to do.  I don't know the right way to identify best balance.  I guessing I could measure and measure and probably find that the best throughput is achived at a CPU avg utilization of 90% or 91%, etc. but...

I'm just wondering if there's a good rule of thumb about this???  I don't want to assume that my testing will take into account all kinds of variations of workloads.  I'd rather play it a bit safe, but not too safe (or else I'm underusing my hardware).

What do you recommend?  What is a smart, performance minded rule of utilization for a multi-threaded, mixed load (some I/O, some CPU) application on Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, I'd suggest 100% is thrashing so wouldn't want to see processes running like that all the time. I've always aimed for 80% to get a balance between utilization and room for spikes / ad-hoc processes.

An approach i've used in the past is to crank up the pool size slowly and measure the impact (both on CPU and on other constraints such as IO), you never know, you might find that suddenly IO becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 4):

CPU utilization shouldn't matter in this i/o intensive workload, you care about throughput, so try using a [hill climbing approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) and basically try programmatically injecting / removing worker threads and track completion progress...

If you add a thread and it helps, add another one. If you try a thread and it hurts remove it.

Eventually this will stabilize.

If this is a .NET based app, hill climbing was added to the .NET 4 threadpool.

UPDATE:

hill climbing is a control theory based approach to maximizing throughput, you can call it trial and error if you want, but it is a sound approach.  In general, there isn't a good 'rule of thumb' to follow here because the overheads and latencies vary so much, it's not really possible to generalize.  The focus should be on throughput & task / thread completion, not CPU utilization.  For example, it's pretty easy to peg the cores pretty easily with coarse or fine-grained synchronization but not actually make a difference in throughput.

Also regarding .NET 4, if you can reframe your problem as a Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach then the threadpool will adjust number of threads to maximize throughput so you don't have to worry about this.

-Rick

Comment: I appeciate the hill climbing approach, but i am specifically looking for rule of thumb, not trial and err, which I said I can do if I need to.

Comment: @user277617: He was saying that the .NET 4 threadpool does the trial and error automatically for you. Which is very interesting if you are.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming nothing else of importance but the OS runs on the machine:

And your load is constant, you should aim at 100% CPU utilization, everything else is a waste of CPU. Remember the OS handles the threads so it is indeed able to run, it's hard to starve the OS with a well behaved program.

But if your load is variable and you expect peaks you should take in consideration, I'd say 80% CPU is a good threshold to use, unless you know exactly how will that load vary and how much CPU it will demand, in which case you can aim for the exact number.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply give your threads a low priority, the OS will do the rest, and take cycles as it needs to do work.  Server 2003 (and most Server OSes) are **very good at this**, no need to try and manage it yourself.

Comment: The OS will most likely do the same if you give the threads normal priority. What you don't want to do is to give them high priority.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used 80% as a general rule-of-thumb for target CPU utilization. As some others have mentioned, this leaves some headroom for sporadic spikes in activity and will help avoid thrashing on the CPU.

Here is a little (older but still relevant) advice from the Weblogic crew on this issue: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/perform/basics.html#wp1132942

If you feel your load is very even and predictable you could push that target a little higher, but unless your user base is exceptionally tolerant of periodic slow responses and your project budget is incredibly tight, I'd recommend adding more resources to your system (adding a CPU, using a CPU with more cores, etc.) over making a risky move to try to squeeze out another 10% CPU utilization out of your existing platform.